# How to count the number of times a column name appears AND that column has a nonblank cell

Tags: excel, countif

I apologize if this is not a 100% clear description, but this is also why I'm asking it, because I'm not sure exactly how to phrase it to search for the answer (so far, fruitless).

I keep stats and records for my soccer team, including which players played against which teams, the results, etc.  Right now I have Table 1 set up so that the player names are in columns A and B (first, last), and the column headers from thereon are the names of the teams we have played, listed chronologically (e.g. Team A, B, C, D, A, C, B, D, etc.).  For every game I update that game's column for every player that played with a W, L or T (this enables me to calculate career win percentage per player, etc.).

In Table 2 I have the same A & B columns showing every player, and a condensed number of columns according to each team (i.e. Team A, B, C, D, etc.).  What I want to do is set Table 2 up so I can show the number of games each player has played against each team, i.e. how many times there is a W, L or T in a given row for a any instance of a given team name in Table 1).

I was hoping something along the lines of this would work for the first player:

```
=COUNTIFS(Attendance!$B2:$BS2,'Players vs.   Teams'!C$2,Attendance!$C3:$BS3,OR("=W","=L","=T"))
```

Alas, it does not.  I get a #VALUE! error back.  My thought process was to count all cells that met **two** requirements:

1. The team name in the first table matches the team name in the second table (e.g. Team A). There will be multiple instances.
2. The cells in that player's row in the first table are nonblank (W,L or T) in columns corresponding to that particular team (Team A).

I know the first `countif` criteria works because if used independently, it returns the number of times a specified team has been played (i.e. is listed in Table 1).  I can't figure out how to count the number of times that has happened *and* a particular player has a non-blank cell in one of those columns in Table 1.  Any thoughts?.....

Comment: I assume this is Excel? I've added this tag.

Comment: Yes sir.  Sorry about that.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use an `OR` function in `COUNTIFS` quite like that, try this approach....

`=SUM(COUNTIFS(Attendance!$C$2:$BS$2,'Players vs.   Teams'!C$2,Attendance!$C3:$BS3,{"W","L","T"}))`

That specifically counts "W","L" and "T", but you could just count non-blanks with this version

`=COUNTIFS(Attendance!$C$2:$BS$2,'Players vs.   Teams'!C$2,Attendance!$C3:$BS3,"<>")`

...and with the $ signs set correctly you should be able to copy that formula across **and** down.....

Edit: ranges were also mismatched sizes, now edited

Comment: I had tried the second string before (with the "<>" criteria), but opted not to do this because I have intermediary summation columns in Table 1.  I just tried the first string you provided, but got another #VALUE! result, saying "A value used in the formula is of the wrong data type."  Again, I split the countifs up into separate cells to try their functionality; the first works perfectly, as does the second (when using SUM(COUNTIFS...).  The seems to be some sort of data type issue, though.

Comment: @hokiemon09 Sorry, I copied your ranges but they are not the same size, both need to start from the same column, presumably C, like this: `=SUM(COUNTIFS(Attendance!$C$2:$BS$2,'Players vs. Teams'!C$2,Attendance!$C3:$BS3,{"W","L","T"}))` - edited abocve....

Comment: Thank you, Barry.  I changed the range from B2:BS2 to C2:BS2 to match the range in the second criteria, and it worked like a charm.  Time to go nerd out on some stats!